# How to submit form after validate all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tyring to validate my form using jquery , form is validating fine but form is not submitted even after i entered all fields correctly,How can i do this ?
Where i am wrong ? Here is my jquery code

```
 <script>  
    $(document).ready (function () {
        $('#first_form').submit (function (e) { 
                 
            e.preventDefault();  
             var first_name = $('#first_name').val(); 
             var email = $('#email').val();     
             var pwd = $('#pwd').val(); 
             
             var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
            
             var city = $('#city').val();
            var state = $('#state').val();
             var country = $('#country').val();
             
              $(".error").remove();  
            if (first_name.length < 1) {  
              $("#usernamemsg").append('<span class="error" style="color:red;">This field is required</span>'); 
            }
            
            if (email.length < 1) {  
              $("#emailmsg").append('<span class="error" style="color:red;">This field is required</span>');    
            }
            if (pwd.length < 1) {  
              $("#pwdmsg").append('<span class="error" style="color:red;">Password must be at least 6 characters long</span>'); 
            }
            $("#first_form").validate({ 
            submitHandler: function(form) {  
                           if ($(form).valid()) 
                               form.submit(); 
                           return false; // prevent normal form posting
                    }
 });
        
    });  
 });
</script>
```

Here is my form,how can i submit form after enter all fields ?

```
            <form action="" method="post" id="first_form">
            <div class="form-field col-md-6">
             <span id="msg"></span>
                <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="first_name"  >
            </div>

            <div class="form-field col-md-6">
                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-field col-md-6">
                <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" required>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix btns-form-main">
                <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" name="submit" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What is this `validate` method you are calling? That is not native jQuery AFAIK, so you must be using some plugin? And why does this get called _inside_ your submit handler only, after you appear to have done a few validations via your own code apparently?

Comment: @CBroe: what is correct solution ?

Comment: Finding it probably starts with answering the questions you were asked for clarification.

Comment: @CBroe not understand your point

Comment: Did you try to add a `console.log(form.valid())` just before `if ($(form).valid())` to see if it is `true` or `false`?

Comment: `$("#first_form").validate()`- that method you are calling here is not part of standard jQuery, so you must be using some plugin. So which one is that? https://jqueryvalidation.org ? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

By `addClass` with `:not()` selector you can do that

```js
$(document).on("submit" , '#first_form:not(.validated)' , function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $this = $(this);
  // do your validation here
  console.log("validating");
  console.log("After Validation Complete.. add the class and submit..");
  // If form is valid
  setTimeout(function(){ // for testing purposes << remove it
    $this.addClass("validated").submit();
  } , 2000); // <<< remove it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="first_form">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This seems an incredibly complicated and round-about way of solving what can be done by simply using the plugin properly.  Can you add an explanation of why you think this is a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the validate function inside the submit function, and since you are using [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), you can specify rules and messages inside the validate function, try the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#first_form").validate({
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) {
            element.after(error);
        },
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            pwd: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 20,
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            if ($(form).valid())
                form.submit();
            return false; // prevent normal form posting
        }
    });
});
```

**Update:** Also add the `required` `class` to fields that you want to add validation on.

Comment: There is no need for a `submitHandler` unless you need to do something special (like submit via AJAX).  The plugin already stops submission if something fails validation, and allows submission if the form is valid - you don't need a `submitHandler` which does that a 2nd time.